# SQL Data-Export- Issue with user function

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I need to export some Data from a SQL Database to a .txt file. I'm exporting the data of the specific columns I need with this query:

```
SELECT Category1, Category2, Category3 
FROM dbo.tbl1
WHERE Category1 = 'JP-4'
AND Category2> 4;
```

I've also got a function to remove the html formatting from the data.

```
SELECT 
Category1, Category2, Category3,
dbo.func_RemoveHTML ([Category3])
FROM dbo.tbl1
WHERE Category1 = 'JP-4'
AND Category2> 4;
```

The function works but this way Category3 is added as an additional column(without the title) behind the Category3 column instead of executing the function on the first Category3 column (if that makes sense. hard to explain)

I've tried to remove

```
SELECT 
Category1, Category2, Category3
```

and just SELECT the column with the function but then the column titles go missing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way ... so you will execute function and result of it will be in 
column of 'Category3'

```
SELECT 
Category1, Category2, dbo.func_RemoveHTML ([Category3]) as 'Category3'    
FROM dbo.tbl1
WHERE Category1 = 'JP-4'
AND Category2> 4;
```

Basically you can select all you want, just once you pick a column or function and use it in select statement you can rename it or add alias using " AS 'SomeName' "